# Как создать страницу в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Знаю, что можно через админ. панель создавать страницы. А я хочу вручную создать в папке шаблона. Например, создан файл about.php рядом с `index.php`. В index пытаюсь добавить ссылку на этот файл `<a href="about.php"></a>`. Почему при клике на ссылку не происходит переход на страницу about?

Comment: возможно ссылка указывает не на тот каталог. Обычно указывают с корня.`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/путь_к_файлу"`

Comment: Интересна причина появления подобного вопроса, скорее всего вызвана не пониманием работы wp

Comment: То что здесь посоветовали - создать шаблон page-about.php - это только шаблон. Но после этого придется все равно в админке создавать страницу. И для нее выбирать шаблон about page. А в вопросе было - как создать страницу в папке шаблона. Меня тоже интересует этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

> Например создан файл about.php рядом с index.php. В index пытаюсь
>   добавить ссылку на этот файл . Почему при
>   клике на ссылку не происходит переход на страницу about?

Потому что так ссылка указывает на файл в корне сайта (точнее в корне будет `a href="/about.php"` А так это относительная ссылка), а не в теме.
Нужно переложи его в корень. Но надо понимать что так он не будет обрабатываться ВП.

А чтобы работал в каталоге темы - нужно создать [шаблон](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F) в соответствии с [иерархией](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2).  Напр `page-about.php`